# Android phone-only image scale factors: is hdpi (1.5x) obsolete?

Tags: android

- ldpi = .75x
- mpdi = 1x
- hdpi = 1.5x
- xhdpi = @2x
- xxhdpi = @3x
- xxxhdpi = @4x

For developing smartphone-only apps (no tablet support), is the userbase for Android phones in hdpi (1.5x) virtually non existent?

Answer (score 0):

The official list can be found from google at https://design.google.com/devices/

I wouldn't worry about it, I only count 3 prominent devices that use that or lower. However, if you're writing a new app you can use vector drawables and the images will be generated for you.